# Table without column specification

Tags: tables

Is there a way to create a table in LaTeX without specifying in advance the number of columns? What I want is something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{amazingtabular}
this & is & a\\
table & without & column specification
\end{amazingtabular}
\end{document}
```

Notice that there is no argument like `{cll}` after the `amazingtable` environment. What I want is that the environment should work for an *arbitrary* number of columns. If possible, I would like to avoid going into math mode to use the `matrix` environment.

Comment: Would there be a problem with simply specifying e.g. 50 columns and then not using all of them?

Comment: It would be better, if we know your real problem. In particular a piece of information of the type:  `the first column is centered, the others left aligned, maximal number of them is 30` would be useful. It seems to be unbelievable, that writing down the column specification is the problem itself.

Comment: They should all be left-aligned, and I very much doubt that their number will exceed 15. The problem is that I'm converting an XML script to LaTeX, and it does not use column specifications.

Comment: You can certainly specify 50 or more columns and only use, say, 10. You still have to inform LaTeX about whether the columns' contents should be typeset centered, justified, flush-right, flush-left, or whatever else. If all columns should be set flush-left, just use `\begin{tabular}{*{50}{l}}`.

Comment: Probably use [`stackengine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the number of columns would be below 30...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{amazingtabular}{\begin{tabular}{*{30}{l}}}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{amazingtabular}
this & is & a\\
table & without & column specification
\end{amazingtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want it to work for an *arbitrary* number of columns.

Comment: @Gaussler Corrected according to your specification.

Comment: @Gaussler TeX will be quite happy to specify 10000 columns, if you like to. Of course, it *won't* be able to typeset a table with 10000 columns, because it can't manage lines longer than about 4.5 meters. I'd say that 100 columns is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @egreg I understand your intentions, but it seems that 10000 is too much. The compilation time was at least 100 times longer than with the value 1000.

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): you can create a table without specifying in advance the number of columns, or only specifying the second column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{}
this  & is      & a \\
table & without & column specification
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{column{2}={c}}
this  & is      & a \\
table & without & column specification
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]